# Play 2.5 && heroku: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: javascript, heroku, playframework, heroku-toolbelt

I know that it is a duplicated question, but I can not find the solution.

I have a very very long string to pass: 
Seq contains **10000 base64 images.**

```
Ok(Json.toJson(seq))
```

When I deploy on **Heroku**, the displayed string is cutted (in the middle of one of the first base64 image), and in the javascript console, it is written:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

How I can fixe it?

PS: I now it is not the best way to transfer this images, but for now, it is way more easy.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of Play 2.5.x are you using? I looks like you are running into this (which might be fixed in 2.5.1) https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5835

Comment: Yes thanks! It is working perfectly now! I update my version to 2.5.1. Do you want to add this answer, for get the credits (it is maybe important for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading to 2.5.1 or higher. This bug was fixed here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5835